# push to mongodb array using dynamic key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to push a data by dynamic key

db structure:

```
{
    "obj1":{
      "array":[
       {
        "field1":"text1"
       },
       {
        "field2":"text2"
       }
      ]
    },
    "id":123;
 },
 {
    "obj2":{
      "array":[
       {
        "field1":"text1"
       },
       {
        "field2":"text2"
       }
      ]
    },
    "id":1234;
 }
```

I'm trying to use variable as a key in map path:

```
var a = 'obj2';
db.collection('fooCollection').update({'id':1234},{$push:{a.array:{  "field3":"text3"}}});
```

if I do:

```
db.collection('fooCollection').update({'id':1234},{$push:{"obj2.array":{ "field3":"text3"}}});
```

it works, but I badly need to use dynamic key.

Comment: Can you clean up your examples?  Your "working" one isn't a valid query at all (my guess is a few missing `"` and a missing `:`, but I'm not sure).

Comment: fixed, made in haste, sorry

Comment: You need to make the key programmatically; I don't think you can create a key from a string concatenation in a literal.

Answer (score 5):

That can't be done with object literals.  Try this:

```
var a = 'obj2';

var pushObj = {};
pushObj[a + '.array'] = { "field3": "text3" };

db.collection('fooCollection').update({ 'id':1234 }, { $push: pushObj });
```

Comment: strangely, I was trying do it 5h ago, then decided to recheck after your message.
And it works -_-